# Keeping track of changes in a database

Tags: database, version-control, sqlite

Let's suppose a system uses a sqlite3 database for its configuration. The system has different versions being used in the marked and all of them require different changes over time. So for example, in table `FOO`, version 1 of the system has rows A and B, while version 2 of the system has rows A, B, E, F.
Is it possible to track these changes in somthing similar to a VCS? Even better would be to be able to merge changes from one version to the next.

Comment: This description is unclear. What to you mean with "track"? Which specific operation(s) do you want to do automatically?

Comment: I want the same  operations I would have in a VCS, mainly see the change history, who changed what in the tables, and being able to merge changes from one version to another, like it's possible to do with branches in git

Comment: Then put the DB (or better, its `.dump` output) into a VCS.

Comment: It currently is in the vcs, but since it's a binary file, it won't do any good. I was wondering fi there is anything better than just putting the dump of the db.